# I am trying to extract data from multiple web pages which are pdf but they have different numbers of tables in each pdf. how do i extract it

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to extract the data from mutiple urls opening into pdf files using powerBI

below is the query

```
let
Source = Pdf.Tables(Web.Contents("https://ifbb.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/07-2023-Jordan-Amat-Results.pdf"), \[Implementation="1.3"\]),


**Page1** = Source{\[Id="Page002"\]}\[Data\],


\#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Page1,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}, {"Column6", type text}, {"Column7", type text}, {"Column8", type text}, {"Column9", type text}, {"Column10", type text}, {"Column11", type text}})
in
\#"Changed Type"
```

I want the Page1 variable to be dynamic since under the same url I have different tables and different urls have different number of tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
let Source = Pdf.Tables(Web.Contents("https://ifbb.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/07-2023-Jordan-Amat-Results.pdf"), [Implementation="1.3"]),
Page1 = Source{[Id=Page & Text.Start(Text.From(List.Max(List.Transform(Source[Id], each Text.From(_)))), 3) & ""]}[Data],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Page1,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}, {"Column6", type text}, {"Column7", type text}, {"Column8", type text}, {"Column9", type text}, {"Column10", type text}, {"Column11", type text}}) in #"Changed Type"
```

This PowerBI code is used to extract data from multiple URLs opening into PDF files. The code first creates a variable called Source that contains the contents of the URL. Then it creates a variable called Page1 that contains the table data from the page with the highest ID number. Finally, it changes the data type of the columns to text. The Page1 variable is made dynamic by using the List.Max function to get the highest ID number from the Source variable and then concatenating it with the string "Page" to create the ID for the Page1 variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot Luca for the help. I tried this code, however i am getting errors. Error 1 : Expression.Error: The import page matches no export. Did you miss a module reference? Error 2 once i click on go to error: Expression.Error: The name 'Page' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This pulls the contents of everything all at once, then you could filter the table you want and promote the first row to column headers

```
let Source = Pdf.Tables(Web.Contents("https://ifbb.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/07-2023-Jordan-Amat-Results.pdf"), [Implementation="1.3"]),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(Source[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))), 
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Data", List,List)   
in  #"Expanded Data"
```

Alternately, change your code like here so that it is a function, name the function **Process**

```
(variable)=>
let Source = Pdf.Tables(Web.Contents("https://ifbb.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/07-2023-Jordan-Amat-Results.pdf"), [Implementation="1.3"]),
Page = Source{[Id=variable]}[Data]
in  Page
```

[image]

then when you want to use it, call from another query such as

```
let Source=Process("Page002") in Source
```